# How to show different layout for landscape and portrait in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Just wanted to know how we can show different layout for landscape and portrait in flutter. In Native for android we just create `layout` and `layout-land` folder and put xml files there and system will automatically detect the appropriate layout for orientation.
Any help on flutter would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use official widget like docs says https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use orientation builder and check inside if the orientation is portrait or landscape.
Check the documentation [here.](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation#:%7E:text=In%20Flutter%2C%20you%20can%20build,change%20the%20number%20of%20columns.)

Sample Code:

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```